# freemarker - Retrieve value from sequences

Tags: freemarker, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Hoping this issue is easy enough to resolve.

I am trying to retrieve a single value from a sequence using FreeMarker via the advanced form PDF functionality in NetSuite.

Here is a snippet of code:

```
          <#assign getOps>
      <#list record.item as assembly>
      {item: ${assembly.item}, op: ${assembly.operationsequencenumber}}
      </#list>
    </#assign>
      
      Number of words: ${getOps?word_list?size}
${getOps}
```

When I print the above, the following is printed:

[image]

I want to be able to capture single values from this sequence, using something similar to ${getOps.item} but an error is fired:

> For "." left-hand operand: Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to
> a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar):
> ==> getOps[2] [in template "template" at line 126, column 3]
>
> ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
>
> - Failed at: ${getOps[2].item} [in template "template" at line 126, column 1]

---

Can you identify the issue here?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are capturing output into a single string there. So it's unstructured, a flat string, therefore you can't traverse it anymore. If you really need to transform the original list, you need to use `?map` (see in the FreeMarker Manual). But Netsuite uses a FreeMarker fork, and I'm not sure if they support `?map`.